# Add TextBox values to Grid in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I have 2 text box and one submit button and one grid in my app. Now i what to add the textbox values to grid while i click the submit button. How to do that?
`

```
[HttpPost]        
        public ActionResult AddToCart(string ItemID, string ItemName, CartToCart cart)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "This is a partial view.";
            List<Models.CartToCart> lst = new List<Models.CartToCart>();
            CartToCart ct = new CartToCart();

            cart.ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(ItemID);
            cart.ItemName = ItemName;
            lst.Add(cart);
            return View(lst);
        }`
```

View

```
        <% using (Html.BeginForm()) 
   { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <input id="ItemID" name="ItemID" type="text" />
    <input id="ItemName" name="ItemName" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
           .Name("Cart")%>
     <% } %>
```

But while i adding 2nd value 1st value replaced by 2nd value. How to append the 2nd value in grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you store the values?  Currently you're creating a new empty list on each POST and adding a single value to that list:

```
List<Models.CartToCart> lst = new List<Models.CartToCart>();
CartToCart ct = new CartToCart();
cart.ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(ItemID);
cart.ItemName = ItemName;
lst.Add(cart);
return View(lst);
```

So you only ever populate the view with the most recent value, throwing away any previous values.  If you want to keep more than just the currently-POSTed value then you'll need to persist them somewhere more permanent, such as a database.  So in your controller action you would insert the new POSTed value into the database.  Then you'd fetch all of the records from the database as your list of values and return that list to the view.

Comment: Actually fist i want to get all item details. Then only i have save the details in database. How to persist my data?

Comment: @user2501044: There are lots of ways to persist your data, using a database or otherwise.  That's a bit broad for a Stack Overflow question, and any tutorial on ASP.NET MVC will include it: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials  I recommend walking through one or more tutorials.